# Refactoring identical models in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, dry

I used a join table solution to create friendships like so:

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :friend, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => :friend_id

  def self.request(user, friend)
    unless user == friend
      current = find_by_user_id_and_friend_id(user, friend)

      unless current
        transaction do
          create :user => user, :friend => friend, :status => "pending"
          create :user => friend, :friend => user, :status => "requested"
        end
      end
    end
  end
...
```

I went to create memberships to groups, and found the same scenario:

```
class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :network

  def self.request(user, network)
    current = find_by_user_id_and_network_id(user, network)

    unless current
      transaction do
        create :user => user, :network => network, :status => "pending"
        create :user => network, :network => user, :status => "requested"
      end
    end
  end
...
```

I made this complex with blocking, and that's a lot of repeated code.

Due to `belongs_to :friend, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => :friend_id`, identifying that key as representing a user specifically, I don't think I can get away with using `Contact` for both user <-> user and user <-> network. I could make it also `belongs_to` a network via `network_id`, but I still feel like I'd have to double the methods to account for that. I suppose I could pass a `type` (`:friend` or `:network`) to every method and use that like:

```
      create :user => user, type => target, :status => "pending"
      create :user => target, type => user, :status => "requested"
```

but, is there a better solution?

Another thought I had was to always use the term `:friend`, but maybe use a mix-in or abstract class and just define the `belongs_to :friend` line differently between the two files.

Comment: You should consider using a Polymorphic association: the model Contact could simply become `Relation` and its role would be to link the `requester` (User) and the `requested` (polymorphic: either a User or a Network). Add a column named `status` in there and both of your models are now merged into one!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Polymoprhic Associations should help with using one model:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations

Comment: you can also get rid of a lot of this code using first_or_create rather than the unless current stuff.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. Nice to know what to look for. I tried the mixin solution and discovered that i also cant create two-way relationships in the case of members, so it will be different. Maybe i should stop being pedantic

Comment: @user1655807 Why can't you "create two-way relationships in the case of members" ?

Comment: create :user => user, :network => network, :status => "pending"
create :user => network, :network => user, :status => "requested"

User to user is two entries. User to network is one.

Answer (score 1):

You can abstract this behaviour into a module called `Requestable`.

```
module Requestable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  class_methods do
    def by_name=(name)
      @name = name
    end

    def request(user, instance)
      # use @name or class name as default
      name = @name || self.class.name.dasherize.to_sym
      # find current relation
      current = self.class.where(user: user, name => instance)

      # create new relations, if needed
      unless current
        transaction do
          create :user => user, name => network, :status => "pending"
          create :user => network, name => user, :status => "requested"
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Now you can dry up your models:

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Requestable
  by_name 'friend'

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :friend, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => :friend_id
end

class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Requestable

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :network
end
```

I didn't debug the code, but the idea is clear, I hope.

Comment: Cool, I'll check it out. Like I mentioned above, the two 'create' statements are going to be a problem since user<->network isn't a two-way relationship. But this gives me something to work with.

Comment: @user1655807 as Philippe noted you should also use polymorphic relations. But it's not a solution for two identical "request" methods.

Comment: @mryoshiji your edit was incorrect. I used `name => ...` intentionally here.